# How to share the same H2 in-memory database among same (identical) load balanced Spring boot services?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, load-balancing, h2

This is not a duplicate question. I'm not asking how do I share the same H2 instance across different Spring boot applications. I know how to do that. My case is different. I have the same Spring boot application (RESTful service) that needs to be load balanced and I need the load balanced instances to share the same H2 in-memory database. The proposed solution for sharing the same H2 instance across different Spring boot applications requires different connection strings in the application.properties file and for one of the applications to be the server for the H2 instance. This is not possible when it is the same Spring boot application load balanced. Therefore, how do I share the same H2 in-memory database among same (identical) load balanced Spring boot services?

Comment: Not sure if H2 can be load balanced or not. But wouldn't something like REDIS be the right solution for this kind of situation.

Comment: @GrinishNepal Can you please point me to an example of how to do this? (This may be the solution that I'm looking for.)

Comment: you will need a redis server to start with but there are others in-memory data store/grids available too, depends on your use case. You will find a lot of blogs online, to start with you can read this https://dzone.com/articles/intro-to-redis-with-spring-boot && https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-redis-tutorial

Comment: @GrinishNepal Thanks. After reading these articles, I don't think this solution will work because it's not embedded like H2.  What other in-memory data store/grids were you thinking of? Whatever the solution is, it has to be the same for all load balanced instances of the same Spring boot application.

Comment: you can connect to the same redis instance with as many spring boot application you want. other options to look at would be apache ignite , hazelcast thats what i can think of.